# About Stackoverflow HTTP cache strategy

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, caching

Hi,
I'm interested to know a little more about how stakoverflow manage his HTTP cache strategy.

I see that the pages are supposed to be cached 60 seconds using these headers

> Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
>   Expires: Mon, 15 Nov 2010 17:56:38 GMT

But I also see this header

> Vary: *

and According [HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.6)

> A Vary header field-value of "*" always fails to match and subsequent requests on that resource can only be properly interpreted by the origin server.

<strike>According my tests, pages are been cached on my browser despites the `Vary` header so I'm a little confused</strike>. I'd like to know the "vision" of the Stackoverflow team about the HTTP cache strategy. The official word about how cache is supposed to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Firefox, but for now I would delete "According my tests, pages are been cached on my browser despites the Vary header". I thought I saw a 304 response serving stackoverflow.com, but I couldn't recreate that again.